# If the complementary language of an recognizable language is a non-recognizable language, is the recognizable language a non-decidable language?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability, turing-recognizable

The complementary language of a recognizable undecidable language is not recognizable.

If the complementary language of an recognizable language is a non-recognizable language, is the recognizable language a non-decidable language?

Answer (score 1):

If a language $L$ is recognizable but it's complement $\overline{L} $ is not, then there is no TM that will halt and accepts a string $w \in \overline{L} $, which implies that there is no TM that will halt and rejects $w \notin L$. However for a language to be decidable there must be a TM that accepts $w$ if it is in $L$ or rejects $w$, otherwise.